# Filter a range in kotlin

Tags: kotlin

In kotlin I want filter a range of `Int` to make odd/even example. so I made a `listOf` range `1..50`

```
val angka = listOf(1..50)
```

followed by applying `filter` for `even` and `filterNot` for `odd`

```
val genap = angka.filter { it % 2 == 0}
val ganjil = angka.filterNot { it % 2 == 0 }
```

then printing both the even/odd lists

```
println("Genap = $genap")
println("Ganjil = $ganjil")
```

I do not see any problems with code, but it does throws exception mentioned below

```
Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch:
public inline operator fun BigDecimal.mod(other: BigDecimal): BigDecimal defined in kotlin
```

Comment: That's a compile error.  Not an exception (an object descending from kotlin.Exception or java.lang.Exception which is thrown at runtime).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is creating a `List<IntRange>` with a single element:

```kotlin
val angka = listOf(1..50)
```

You should instead directly filter the range:

```
val angka = 1..50
```

The rest of the code is correct.

Answer (score 1):

If you are a beginner with Kotlin, please either specify the type of values explicitly, or turn on the local variable type hits.

This way you would have noticed that the code is not *perfect*. Your list `angka` is not a list of type `List<Int>`, but a list of type `List<IntRange>`.

Meaning that you are not doing `Int % 2 == 0`, but in fact, you are doing `IntRange % 2 == 0`.

If you want to get a list from a range, you need to do `(x..y).toList()`. So your code will be:

```
val angka = (1..50).toList() //or since you are not using this list anywhere else, just leave it as `1..50` and the filter will work fine on the IntRange.

val genap = angka.filter { it % 2 == 0 }
val ganjil = angka.filterNot { it % 2 == 0 }

println("Genap = $genap")
println("Ganjil = $ganjil")
```

With output:

```
Genap = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30, 32, 34, 36, 38, 40, 42, 44, 46, 48, 50]
Ganjil = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23, 25, 27, 29, 31, 33, 35, 37, 39, 41, 43, 45, 47, 49]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your declaration of all numbers is wrong... it is like this `val angka: List<IntRange> = listOf(1..50)`. You created a list of ranges contaning one range.

This should work:

```
val angka = 1..50
val genap = angka.filter { it % 2 == 0}
val ganjil = angka.filterNot { it % 2 == 0 }
println("Genap = $genap")
println("Ganjil = $ganjil")
```